# Get data/backup out of a bootlooping Nexus6P

Tags: backup, boot-loop, nexus-6p

My phone got stuck in a bootloop since yesterday and now I am trying to get out any data/backup I can. After dozens of tries (most of the times it just reboots when I choose to get into recovery from the bootloader), I managed to get to recovery and get the whole `sdcard` contents with `adb pull`. I am now trying to get backups of some, if not all, apps.

I tried `adb backup -all -apk -f -backup.ab` but since my phone has the `TWRP` recovery, this doesn't work.

1. Is it ok if I just get a backup of the `data` partition? Will I able to restore apps from this partition to a new phone (possibly not a Nexus6P). Do encryption/lock settings have a role in this?
2. Is it a good idea to try and flash a factory image, so that I have the factory recovery, and try running the same `adb` command? I am not even sure I will be able to get into recovery again after that.

I am really afraid to anything at this point, before I know that there is a good chance I'll have any success. I can get to the bootloader easily, but trying to get into recovery fails most of the times.

Comment: Factory recovery won't offer you ADB access at all. As you've got TWRP: have you considered using its integrated Nandroid backup? There are tools (e.g. Titanium Backup) which can even extract single apps (and their data) from Nandroid backups.

Comment: I'm actually in the process of doing just that. I just need the `data` partition, right?

Comment: Can't hurt to have a full backup – but yes, to restore apps and data the `/data` partition should suffice.

Comment: Tried it and reboots randomly while making the backup...

Comment: I never had that – first time I hear a device rebooting randomly while making a Nandroid in recovery. Apart from taking an image of the `/data` partition (using `dd`) I don't know what you could do; and while with that image you could access all data in it from your PC, restoring will be tricky at best.